# How can i set a specific date to be a non business day in fullcalendar 5?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I want to define a particular day for which businessHours are ignored and the day is completely marked as non-business but i can't find how can it be accomplished in the documentation

```
businessHours: {
   daysOfWeek: [1,2,3,4,5],
   starTime: '09:00',
   endTime: '18:00'
},
```

i want to mark '2023-02-16' for example so that all day is non-business

i really don't know where to start with this. Maybe can someone point me in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your best option is to make an event feed for occasional non-business days which aren't part of the normal routine, and render those events as [background events](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/background-events).

You're right that the `businessHours` feature doesn't allow for one-off days, it only lets you set a recurring pattern.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to create full day background event with some blocking feature. It's a little more work but not much more